# Python-style multi-line string continuations in Julia

Tags: string, julia

In python, you can use the `\` symbol at the end of a line to concatenate a string on the next line. Is there a similar construct in Julia?

For example, I'd like to log a long line of text as one line:

```
@info "asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd ..... end of line"
```

How can I wrap that text over two lines, to make it easier to read in my editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to avoid introducing newline characters, then the simplest option is to use `*` as the string concatenation operator:

```
@info "asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd " *
    "asdasd asdasd asdasd asdasd ..... end of line"
```

Comment: you are fast :).

Comment: Thanks. Will this create 2 strings and concatenate them at runtime, allocating a third string?

Comment: I'm not sure, but if I run `foo() = "hello " * "world"; @btime foo();`, I only see one allocation, so I think the compiler is smart enough to optimize away the concatenation. At any rate, I wouldn't think that logging would be a performance critical part of an application.

Comment: You can also just break the line in the middle of the string, without concatenation. That will introduce a newline, `\n`, in the string at the point where you break the line. Depends on what you want.